# Verbb Navigation Plugin Assistance needed

Tags: craft3, plugin-navigation

Good morning and thank you in advance. I have one Verbb navigation called main. Underneath that, I have three nodes (see image). Under those nodes are regular links. I want my template to pull only the links from a specific node (Business Environment) under the main navigation, how would I go about doing that?

I know this is the code to get all nav: 
`{% set nodes = craft.navigation.nodes('main').all() %}` but how would I access just Business Environment?

[image: Verbb Naviation Setup]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use the [positionedBefore](https://verbb.io/craft-plugins/navigation/docs/getting-elements/node-queries#positionedBefore) query. Let's say `Node 2` has the ID of `1000`. Then you would write it like this

```
{% set nodes = craft.navigation.nodes('main')
    .positionedBefore(1000)
    .all() %}
```

The output would be all nodes before the node with the ID of 1000. In your case just *Business Environment*.

With [descendantOf](https://verbb.io/craft-plugins/navigation/docs/getting-elements/node-queries#descendantOf) you would get all items within your specified node for example. Just check the documentation an all available [node queries](https://verbb.io/craft-plugins/navigation/docs/getting-elements/node-queries).

To get the ID of the node just use the inspector in the control panel, go to your navigation and look for the `data-id="XXXX"` of the node element.

Comment: Thanks Chris. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Hi Chris I have the same problem but don't see the data-id anywhere in the inspector not sure why

Comment: Not to worry I found it using node.id :))

Comment: What if the criteria for finding a specific node was the value of a custom field?